# Use same component with multiple routes, depending on path component type

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to use one component for multiple routes, but depending on the type of the path component a different action has to be performed. I have three main views:

1. `LevelOneView`: This is the landing page, and only shows a search widget. Once the query has been setup, it redirects to the `/search` path and stores the query in `VueX`
2. `LevelTwoView`: This view shows the result of the query. Once the user clicks on the result, it brings them to the `/:id` path
3. `LevelThreeView`: This view shows the details of the listing

These three views need to share some of the paths. The idea is the following:

1. `/search` => Go to `LevelTwoView`, no special work
2. `/:city` => A location (`london`, `newyork`, ...) can be inserted and it should go to the `LevelTwoView` with the query already set to search only listings available in that region. The url should be `/search`
3. `/:id` => Go to `LevelThreeView` using the `id` as a parameter for the fetch req. This is a number

I set up a `beforeEnter` guard on the `/:city` route so that it checks if the path param is a number, and in that case it should redirect to the `LevelThreeView`. This works fine if I am going from the `/search` path to the `/:id` (or even directly to the `/:id` path from the outside), but if I am going from a `LevelThreeView` to a `LevelThreeView` it does not work and returns this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
    eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2051
    abort @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2082
    eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2131
    beforeEnter @ router.js?41cb:43
    iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2120
    step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1846
    eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1847
    eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2139
    eval @ main.js?56d7:115
    iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2120
    step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1846
    step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1850
    runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1854
    confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2147
    transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2034
    push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2365
    eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2779
    push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2778
    goToListing @ ListingCard.vue?6c5e:147
    click @ ListingCard.vue?917d:18
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
    original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911
```

I set up the router in the following way:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'LevelOne',
      component: LevelOneView,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // Clear the query
        store.commit('resetQuery');
        return next();
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/search',
      name: 'LevelTwo',
      component: LevelTwoView
    },
    {
      path: '/:city',
      name: 'LevelTwoWithCity',
      component: LevelTwoView,
      beforeEnter(to, _, next) {
        // Strip the leading slash
        let toPath = to.path.replace("/", "").toLowerCase();

        // Check if the path is a number and push the lv3 view
        if (!isNaN(toPath)) {
          console.log("Router: found valid path for lv 3")
          const id = parseInt(toPath);
          console.log(id);
          return next({name: 'LevelThree', params: { id: id }});
        } 

        // Load up the query
        let query = store.getters.getQuery;

        // Get the name of all the regions, as a list, to lower case
        let regions = query.regions.map(el => el.name.toLowerCase());

        // Check if we have a matching one
        if (regions.includes(toPath)) {
          // First, deactivate them all
          query.regions.map(el => el.value = false)

          // Then, activate only the one that matched
          query.regions.filter(el => el.name.toLowerCase().includes(toPath)).map(el => el.value = true);

          // Commit the query
          store.commit('setQuery', query);
        }

        return next();
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/:id',
      name: 'LevelThree',
      component: LevelThreeView,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        console.log("Inside Level3 beforeEnter");
        next();
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/not-found',
      name: '404',
      component: NotFound,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      component: NotFound,
    },
  ]
})
```

I am a beginner at this so I might be making a trivial mistake. If anyone can give me any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have been able to find a "workaround". For each of the routes, you can define [aliases](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias). So I changed the code to use them, and load up all the possible routes at start up:

```js
// Generate the aliases
let cities = myCities.map(el => "/" + el.name.toLowerCase());

// Get the base case (i.e. the first element to have something to match against)
let baseCity = cities.splice(0, 1)[0];

export default new Router({
  ...
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      ...
    },
    {
      path: '/search',
      ...
    },
    {
      path: baseCity,
      name: 'LevelTwoWithCity',
      component: LevelTwoView,
      alias: cities,
      ... // Here I set up the query object to be passed on
    },
    {
      path: '/:id',
      name: 'LevelThree',
      component: LevelThreeView
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      component: NotFound,
    },
  ]
})
```

in theory, this could be implemented dinamically using the `addRoutes()` method described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes)